# XML : tools for re-indenting XML in batch mode

Tags: xml, batch-file, indentation

I have a whole lot of XML files, badly indented.

I wish to write a script or use a tool which re-indents all the files.

Is there such a tool, or a nice library in a mainstream scripting language (preferred are Ruby and Python), or in Java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for an [XML pretty printer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Pretty_Printer).

Here is an [online](http://tools.decisionsoft.com/xmlpp.html) tool, that uses [xmlpp](http://www.cheztabor.com/xmlpp/index.htm) under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to batch prettify them yourself and you're using Linux, the following script should work. It will create copies of the original files prepended with pretty_:

```
for i in *.xml; do xmllint --format "$i" > pretty_"$i"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a large list of options to do it:

http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/pretty.html#d8578e19

The main ones that I'd use are the xslt stylesheet, or HTML Tidy.